# c# I need to add different values for the same variable in a loop

Tags: c#

I have a loop which repeats 5 times. In that loop I have random numbers being generated. I find the max of the numbers and add them up for a total.

The problem is, the total is different for each iteration and I need to add each total together to find a grand total but I am not sure how.

```
        Random random = new Random();

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)

    {

    int Rnd1R1 = random.Next(1, 7);
    int Rnd1R2 = random.Next(1, 7);
    int Rnd1R3 = random.Next(1, 7);
    int Rnd1R4 = random.Next(1, 7);
    int Rnd1R5 = random.Next(1, 7);
    int Rnd1R6 = random.Next(1, 7);
    int Rnd2R1 = random.Next(1, 7);
    int Rnd2R2 = random.Next(1, 7);
    int Rnd2R3 = random.Next(1, 7);
    int Rnd2R4 = random.Next(1, 7);
    int Rnd3R1 = random.Next(1, 7);
    int Rnd3R2 = random.Next(1, 7);

    Console.WriteLine("~~~~~~New Round~~~~~~");
    Console.WriteLine("~~~~~~First Roll~~~~~~");
    Console.WriteLine("~~~~~~Press Enter~~~~~~");
    Console.ReadKey();
    Console.WriteLine("Player 1 rolls... (Press Enter)");
    Console.ReadKey();
    Console.WriteLine(Rnd1R1);
    Console.WriteLine(Rnd1R2);
    Console.WriteLine(Rnd1R3);
    Console.WriteLine("Player 2 rolls... (Press Enter)");
    Console.ReadKey();
    Console.WriteLine(Rnd1R4);
    Console.WriteLine(Rnd1R5);
    Console.WriteLine(Rnd1R6);

    Console.WriteLine("~~~~~~Second Roll~~~~~~");
    Console.WriteLine("~~~~~~Press Enter~~~~~~");
    Console.ReadKey();
    Console.WriteLine("Player 1 rolls... (Press Enter)");
    Console.ReadKey();
    Console.WriteLine(Rnd2R1);
    Console.WriteLine(Rnd2R2);
    Console.WriteLine("Player 2 rolls... (Press Enter)");
    Console.ReadKey();
    Console.WriteLine(Rnd2R3);
    Console.WriteLine(Rnd2R4);

    Console.WriteLine("~~~~~~Third Roll~~~~~~");
    Console.WriteLine("~~~~~~Press Enter~~~~~~");
    Console.ReadKey();
    Console.WriteLine("Player 1 rolls... (Press Enter)");
    Console.ReadKey();
    Console.WriteLine(Rnd3R1);
    Console.WriteLine("Player 2 rolls... (Press Enter)");
    Console.ReadKey();
    Console.WriteLine(Rnd3R2);
    Console.WriteLine("~~~~~~End of Round~~~~~~");

    int Max1 = (Math.Max(Math.Max(Rnd1R1, Rnd1R2), Rnd1R3)) + (Math.Max(Rnd2R1, Rnd2R2)) + Rnd3R1;
    int Max2 = (Math.Max(Math.Max(Rnd1R4, Rnd1R5), Rnd1R6)) + (Math.Max(Rnd2R3, Rnd2R4)) + Rnd3R2;
    Console.WriteLine(Max1);
    Console.WriteLine(Max2);
```

Comment: Do you have some existing code attempting this?  Helps to give Users better ability to answer you the first time

Comment: that image is unreadable. Post actual text instead please. Should actually be quicker to copy and paste your code than make a picture of it, surely?

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The loop repeats the code for 5 iterations

Comment: store your variable values in a collection /array.

Comment: Ive not done much programming. I will do this. How would I answer my question though?

Comment: Any time you find yourself using variables named `something1`, `something2`, ... you should probably be using an array or list.

Comment: Removing the code defaces the question.  Stop doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand correctly

```
int total=0;  //before loop
```

and

```
total+=Max1+Max2;  //in loop after Max2
```

or

```
total=total+Max1+Max2;
```

this way your sum is remembered in each iteration